# `ng-class` not working on functional call from included template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have my main template called `home.html`, the controller is `homeController` applied throw :
`$routeProvider` :

```
$routeProvider
    .when ("/", {
        templateUrl : "views/home.html",
        controller  : "homeController"
});

$routeProvider
    .otherwise ({
        redirectTo:'/'
});
```

works fine. I have seperate `html` template for `header' which included in the`home.html` like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <ng-include src="'/views/header.html'"></ng-include>
    <div class="globe">
        <div class="progName">
            <div class="swiper"></div>
            <h2 class="active">
                <span class="title">
                    {{activeApp.name}}
                </span>
                <span class="note">{{activeApp.note}}</span>
            </h2>
            <h2 class="que t{{$index+1}}" ng-click="activate(app)" ng-repeat="app in queApp">{{app.name}}</h2>

        </div>
```

for the `header` i have seperate `controller` called 'header.js`which is included in the`index.html` file.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script/factory/server.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script/controllers/header.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script/directives/home/programNames.js"></script>
```

In the header, there is a class, i want to apply by conditionally, so i added the condition in the `header.html` file (which is included)

in the `header.js` (headerController) I am trying to add the conditonal class, but not working:

my header.js:

```
angular.module("tcpApp")
    .controller('header', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.show = false;

        $scope.menuHandler = function () {
            $scope.show = !$scope.show;
            console.log("i am called");
        }

    }]);
```

What i am missing here? the way i am adding the `controller` is wrong? or i need to write the function withing parent controller `homeController` itself?

can't I keep seperate controller for header and include with other template?

Andy one help me handle?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Header html :

```
<header ng-controller="header" >
    <h1><a href="#">TCP</a></h1>
    <nav>
        <a class="menu" ng-click="menuHandler()" href="#">Menu</a>
        <span ng-class="{'activate':show}">
            <a href="#"><span>All</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>Important</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>Design</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>Supply</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>Contruction</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span>Issue Log</span></a>
        </span>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Please add `header.html`

Comment: Where i need to add that? Basically the `header` included underneath the `home controller` is that right? and i have seperate controller for `header'

Comment: As far as I understand, you are trying `ng-class` in `header.html`. which is probably scope issue

Comment: Yes. i added my header.html for your reference.

Comment: As a clue, when i keep my `header` out side of `ng-view` works fine.

Comment: does your `console.log("i am called");` is getting printed?

Comment: Yes. exactly, I am getting out put. that's what i am not able to understand the issue.

Comment: Can you try to remove the '/' in the ng-include statement of header.html
<ng-include src="'views/header.html'"></ng-include>
I guess this will solve the problem.

Comment: the problem is that the ng-include uses the current controller which is the one used in the I assume index.html. which is where the show scope variable is defined... in your controller you define a new one... you can probably solve it with $parent.show, if you have them in some sort of hierarchy, otherwise you can pass the scope in the ng-include or just define the header function in the controller which holds the ng-include

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your home.html :

```
<div class="content">
    <ng-include src="views/header.html"></ng-include>
    //code here
</div>
```

Remove the '/' at the starting of the path of header.html template.

This should do the trick, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<span ng-class="show?'activate':'other-class'">
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, I am using a module for `scroll` purpose. when i comment that, it works.

```
var newHash = 'anchor3';
        if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
          $location.hash('anchor3');
        } else {
          $anchorScroll();
        }
```

I commented all above. thanks every one!